# How to keep a user logged in until browser is closed in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I use Meteor default account-password package.
The user login data (loginToken, userId and loginTokenExpires) is stored in localStorage, so when I close a browser the user is still logged in. How to prevent it? Is it possible to store the user data in sessionStorage?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Accounts.config({loginExpirationInDays: 0});
```

The docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config say (I have not tried it myself but sounds like it should work):

> The number of days from when a user logs in until their token expires
>   and they are logged out. Defaults to 90. Set to null to disable login
>   expiration.

UPDATED ANSWER:
You can clean up the localstorage when the browser is about to close, like this:

```
Template.body.rendered = function () {
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    // You can either remove the login tokens manually from localstorage like this:
    // localStorage.removeItem(key);

    // Alternatively you should be able to log out Meteor here (not tested), eg:
    // Meteor.logout();
  });
};
```

Comment: It does not work. I think loginExpirationInDays means that loginToken never expires.

Comment: This solution is ok, but it does not help if the browser was for example killed (not exited normally).

Comment: Agree - there should be a better way to do it... but I'm not sure it's possible with localstorage. Here's the rationale behind using localstorage for sessions if you're interested https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/14/session-cookies

Comment: Btw., another approach could be to log out any users when you start the webapp. Session.set() vars are automatically migrated across hot code pushes (but not reloads), so combining that with a cookie and you should be able to figure out if it's a "new session" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this solution in another topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64464638/11220998

```
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('session') === null) {
    Meteor.logout();
  }
  window.onload=function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('session','on');
  };
```

User will be logged out if it's a new session and not on reload of the page.