# logout a meteor user on window/tab close but not on page refresh.

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, onbeforeunload, meteor-accounts

I have used `window.onbeforeunload` to logout a meteor user on browser tab close. It works fine with tab close but my user gets log out on page refresh which I do not want. Is there any solution to this problem. I want user to not logout on page refresh. I am new in Meteor. Any help would be highly appreciated. The code I have used for this is

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         Meteor.logout();
      }
```

Comment: You might be interested in those posts on Meteor forum: https://forums.meteor.com/t/user-logout-when-browser-is-closed-but-leave-logged-in-when-tab-is-closed-like-old-php-apps/30635 and https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-accounts-remember-me-option/26295

Comment: I read the solution but it is kind of same as it will log you out once you refresh the page.
LoginToken removed = log out on session end = (page refresh || closed browser)

Comment: That is the point: there is few technical differences in these 2 scenarios. Nevertheless, have you really tried the linked article? https://developers.blink.it/index.php/home/meteor-automatic-logout-on-browser-close

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new to meteor too and after many tries I found this solution :

```
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('session') === null) {
    Meteor.logout();
  }
  window.onload=function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('session','on');
  };
```

This code is in my Meteor.startup function. Like that, user will be logged out on meteor startup only if it is a new session and not a refresh of the page.